# Sequelize hasMany is working fine but the inverse relation is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to work with mysql relations in Node Js(express Js) using Sequelize.

`User.hasMany(Post);`  work just fine, but when i try to inverse it in Post model like: `Post.belongsTo(User);`

**got this error:** 
 throw new Error(${source.name}.${_.lowerFirst(Type.name)} called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model);

Error: post.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

**User model like:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');

const Post = require('./Post');

const User = db.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notNull: true
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notNull: true
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notNull: true
    }

});

User.hasMany(Post);

module.exports = User;
```

**And Post model like:**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../config/db');

const User = require('./User');

const Post = db.define('post', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },

    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notNull: true
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        notNull: true
    },
    author: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        notNull: true
    }
});

Post.belongsTo(User);

module.exports = Post;
```

**How can i solve this problem?
Thanks everyone...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct your model definition exports as functions and define **associate** function in each model definition function like this and call it all after all models are registered in some module like database.js:

user.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
   ...

  User.associate = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Post)
  }
```

post.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('post', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
  ...
  Post.associate = function (models) {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User)
  }
```

Comment: you should not import model definitions in each other model files to associate them. First you need to register your models, second you need to call all associate functions of registered model definition function. Don't do cyclic references of your model definitions.

Comment: if i write these two models in one file, then hasMany and belongsTo both work fine. but i want in separate file.

Comment: Define them as functions with associate function like I shown above. And then in something like database.js call all model definition functions and after that call all associate functions

Comment: and how exactly i can call all associate function? can you please describe for me?

Comment: Worked!!! got it from here... https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js